# If between two different characters in a text file, Python

Tags: python, if-statement, between

I am basically trying to use python for a find and replace, but make it only apply to strings between "{s:" and the following "},". I have a long text file of many of the following:

```
["c", "DashedSentence", {s: "Yo limpio mi cuarto todos los sábados."},
      "Question",       {q: "¿Cuándo limpio mi cuarto?",
                         as: ["Todos los sábados.",
                              "Todos los domingos."]}],

["c", "DashedSentence", {s: "Nosotros contestamos el correo cada semana."},
      "Question",       {q: "¿Con qué frecuencia contestamos el correo?",
                         as: ["Cada semana.",
                              "Cada dos semanas."]}],
```

In the end, I want phrases grouped together by underscores within the "s:" sections, by replacing " mi " with " mi_" to yield "mi_cuarto", and similarly with "los" "el" ... and many more that aren't in the given examples.

All I have so far is:

```
s = open("stimuli.txt").read()

word = [' mi ','los ']
phrase = [' mi_',' los_']

for i in range(len(word)):
    if BETWEEN "{s:" and "},":
        s = s.replace(word[i],phrase[i])

f = open("stimuli_phrases.txt", 'w')
f.write(file)
```

Of course, BETWEEN isn't real, that's what I'm looking for. I might not be approaching the problem the right way, so I'm also open to any alternative ideas! I appreciate the help, thanks!

edit: The desired output groups noun phrases and prepositional phrases with in the {s:} sections, like so:

```
["c", "DashedSentence", {s: "Yo limpio mi_cuarto todos_los_sábados."},
      "Question",       {q: "¿Cuándo limpio mi cuarto?",
                         as: ["Todos los sábados.",
                              "Todos los domingos."]}],

["c", "DashedSentence", {s: "Nosotros contestamos el_correo cada_semana."},
      "Question",       {q: "¿Con qué frecuencia contestamos el correo?",
                         as: ["Cada semana.",
                              "Cada dos semanas."]}],
```

Comment: You might want to study the `re` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Please show expected result.

Comment: Your `as` examples are confusing and do not match the `s` strings. This can be solved with regular expressions, but the `as` phrases would require some level of natural language processing to yield that type of result.

Comment: The whole text file is to be used on an internet based experiment platform called Ibex Farm. I don't know what is supposed to match between as phrases and s strings, but the format I have presented is exactly what it needs to be for the platform I'm using, and it works without any issue (i.e. the question is given with two clickable answers below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you gave is [JSON formatted](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation), which mean it could easily be parsed with the builtin [python json library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html):

```
import json

with open("/path/to/your/file", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data:
    try:
        s = item['s']
    except (TypeError, KeyError):
        pass
```

Of course, if you do not want or can parse this file as json, you could use the [re library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html):

```
import re
to_process = re.findall("{s:\"(.+)}\"", yourtext)
```

> To learn or practice with regex, look at there: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Exactly, I just spotted that too. Thanks

Comment: Considering lack of quotes in object keys, I'd rather use yaml.

Comment: Thanks so much for the JSON library recommendation. I need to study up on it a bit, to make it work... for now, copying and pasting the code you've provided (but with my file path), it's giving me the error --
 JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes --  but you're right that this is a .js file... kind of... it's a text file that I copy and paste into a larger .js file that is used by Ibex Farm for an online experiment. I'm not sure if their formatting requirements are exactly the same as JSON, but at least I've got a good place to start looking. Thanks!!